# Fill Dataframe column based on values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe with several columns, each column has binary values. for each columns I have a numpy array with some values with same length of the column.

I need to fill the column with the numpy array but with one condition: fill only if the value in the dataframe column is 0, if it's one don't fill from the numpy array.

Using for loops I would get something like this:

```
 for col in df.columns:
  for i in df[col]:
    if df.loc[i,col] == 0:
      df.at[i,col] = arr[i,col]
    else:
      continue
```

However this is slow and my dataframe is a bit big (10k row * 180 columns), I'm looking if there's any elegant pythonic way to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
df=df.mask(df==0,arr)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26597062)

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas How on God's green earth is this not an answer?

Comment: @cs95 My reasoning when in the review queue: SO doesn't provide a clear distinction whether a code-only answer is a "low-quality answer" or "not an answer" while in the review queue. From my standpoint, the above is a high quality **comment**, but not an **answer**. An answer would warrant an explanation what `mask` does, which the current iteration fails to deliver, ultimately ending up value-less to the community besides the OP. This is a personal opinion so feel free to disagree